# How to debug the Electron main process?

Tags: electron, electron-react-boilerplate

I'm working on [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/) and I'm stuck on how to debug its main process (such as the `src/main/main.ts` file.

To reproduce my situation, simply follow the below steps, as documented in the above link:

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch main https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate.git electron-react-boilerplate
cd electron-react-boilerplate
npm i 
npm start
```

Now, I learnt how to debug the client side (browser side) js/ts script, as it is as simple as opening the dev tools and open the sourcemap-ed files, I can place a breakpoint.

But how is the main process, the electron process? I quickly googled it and found a [github issue](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/issues/1648) and the [Debugging the Main Process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/debugging-main-process) guide page, it says:

> Connect Chrome by visiting chrome://inspect and selecting to inspect the launched Electron app present there

So do I need to modify the package.json file in order to be able to debug the electron process files? (I tried to test with adding `--inspect=5858 --remote-debugging-port=9223`, opening a chrome with `--remote-debugging-port=9223`, opening "localhost:5858", or "chrome://inspect", but nothing happens. The devices tabs does not show the electron instance either.)

What am I missing with my setup? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using an IDE or a text editor?

Comment: I use vscode editor.

Comment: Have you tried and had any success with this Electron document link: [Debugging in VSCode](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/debugging-vscode)?

Comment: Yes, in the simple Electron setup I can successfully debug it.

Comment: Currently I suspect the issue is from this issue on github, so working on it: https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/issues/2757

Answer (score 0):

If you are still facing the same issue it seems that they have released a fix for this,
[the commit that fixed the issue](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/commit/b32c5627fc0c2cac87b4c92384e3af7d965731ca).
I was able to debug both main and renderer after this.